# Transform coordinates length to pixel length?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, transform

Is there a function to transform a coordinates length to a pixel length?

I need this function for cropping and scaling map images to be inserted as layers in an OpenLayers Map.

The map images are already adapted to an OSM map and therefore have an "extent" BBOX.

This feature already exists when using `ol.source.ImageWMS` and a WMS software. The WMS software is too cumbersome for me, also because there is a database needed. Unfortunately the values that are calculated are not retrievable.

I can already calculate the pixel width and height from the extent coordinates, using rule of three. More specific (with rotation) the calculation is also possible with the Pythagorean theorem. For this I only need a default, like for example: 20000 lon = 5000 pixels. But the problem is the projection. For each projection such a default value is needed. Or each projection must be transformed into a default projection. It would be simpler, if it would be transformed into pixels.

Example:

```
// var extent = [minX,minY,maxX,maxY];
var extent = [1002345.9874,5002345.9875,1102345.9876,6002345.9877];
ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, EPSG:3857, Pixel)
// result: [minX,minY,maxX,maxY]
// result: [50,60,150,120]
```

With this and together with the function `map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize())` it can then be calculated whether the extent of the image layer is outside the map viewbox. With this outside pixel length then cropping can be done.

The problem is the zoom. At each zoom level the ratio of coordinate length to pixel length is different.

There is the function `ol.source.ImageStatic`, but with this the image is not scaled or cropped. With high resolution map images this overloads the browser.

I have already found a somewhat cumbersome solution and am looking for a simpler one like in the example.

Comment: Pixel dimensions in Web Mercator are pretty much useless, as are ground units in 3857. You probably need to re-think this task in terms of meaningful units.

Comment: What's wrong with `ol.source.ImageStatic`? See example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html

Comment: @Vince, please visit ol.source.ImageWMS. No Tile or Image Layer works without pixels.

Comment: @TomazicM, ol.source.ImageStatic → "With high resolution map images this overloads the browser." The Images have a size from 1-10 MB, and i set no limit how much images the user can loaded in the map, by more than 2000 Images. 5x2000=10000MB in the browser. Or 5*100=500MB. The example from OL have only 500KB.

Comment: And how do you intend to solve this problem with cropping and scaling? Please edit your question with your last comment and then explain you idea of solving the problem.

Comment: @TomazicM, cropping and scaling for the images is with   ol.source.ImageWMS no work for OL but for server scripts (PHP, Python, ..., with GDImage or ImageMagick ...). But unfortunately OL sends only the Width and Height, but not the Crop data, to the server.

Comment: And what would the crop data be? What is sent are `BBOX` coordinates and size of desired image. That's all the crop data that is needed for server. Client has no idea/info about image size on the server, so it cant send any other crop data.

Comment: @TomazicM, you're wrong about that. OL can, if it cropped, also calculate the total size of the (scaled) image. Because it also calculates the total size without cropping in smaller zoom levels and the total size with cropping in pixels. There is a function in the OL script called `coordinateToPixelTransform`. But it is not available. Crop data can look like this: `[left,bottom,right,top]` in pixel. Example: `[0,50,25,10]` in pixel.

Comment: Crop pixels are relative to what?

Comment: @TomazicM, to the scaled image. The rest is calculated on the server, with rule of three and so on.

Comment: and by the way, the solution is: `map.getPixelFromCoordinate([x,y])`, with a bit of own calculation. Thanks @Mike.

Comment: There's no need for a database source for any layer in a WMS, that's just one option